# Angular 6 - How to Join DB object with Subscribe

Tags: database, angular, join, subscribe

I am working by my own on a app with Angular 6 / Flask. I am currently facing an issue and i am not able to find anything whivh is suitting it on the web. Here is my issue :

I have 3 Model : Project, Consultant and Client. To simplify, a Project have the id of a Consultant and a Client, and also two dates. What i want to do is to :

1. Get the list of all my projects
2. Iterate on this list to handle each project
3. Get the Consultant from its id
4. Get the Client from its id
5. Set an object with the Consultant, the Client and the two dates
6. Add this project to a list
7. Display the list

In fact, my purpose here is to be able to display information of the Consultant and the Client of each project so i need to get the object and not just their id. So i tried to do something from what i found :

```
ngOnInit() {
this.projectsListSubs = this.projectsApi
  .getProjects()
  .flatMap(params => {
      params.forEach(elem => {
      this.project.start_date = elem.start_date;
      this.project.end_date = elem.end_date;
      return  [this.consultantsApi.getConsultant(elem.consultant_id),this.clientsApi.getClient(elem.client_id)]
    }
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.dataList);
  })
  .subscribe(params => {
    this.project.consultant = params[0].firstName + " " + params[0].lastName;
    this.project.client = params[1].name;
    this.dataList.push(this.project);
  });
```

}

Of course, it doesn't work. I think this code is garbage and I am not able to find a proper way to manage this case. Could you please help me on this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you not join it in the backend and avoid yourself a lot of data manipulation in the front-end?

Comment: Yes i though about it but before i would like to be sure that there is no "simple" ways to do that because it seems to me that this is pretty common so i don't know. But at the end yes if i have no solution i would proceed like that.